# Error installing Laravel Elixir on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, npm, laravel-elixir

I am trying to install Laravel Exlixir on Windows 10.

I installed this: [npm-windows-upgrade](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/npm-windows-upgrade)
nodejs version: 4.5.0
npm version: 3.10.8

```
npm install --no-bin-links
```

Getting errors:

> npm WARN deprecated tough-cookie@2.2.2: ReDoS vulnerability parsing
>   Set-Cookie https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/130
>
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
>
> npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program 
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "--no-bin-links"
>
> npm ERR! node v4.5.0
>
> npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
>
> npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded
>
> npm-debug.log: [npm-debug.log file](https://gist.github.com/SigalZ/f2df26a3dcb7ac7afe5994ae5384efdc)

I've been trying to install this thing for a day and a half now. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to use: npm install without the --no-bin-links